# Implicit appending method is not working properly

Tags: scala

I am trying to write an implicit append class that has an append method. The method should add the String to the end of the file.

```
     def AppendToFile(file: File, str: String): Unit = {
    val append = new FileWriter(file)
    try 
      append.append(str).append("\n")  
    finally  
      append.close         
  }
  implicit class RichAppend(p: Path) {
      def append(fileName: String) = AppendToFile(p.toFile,fileName)
 }
```

however, when I run my test I get an error.

```
  "[Second line
[info]   ]
[info]   " did not equal "[line_1
[info]   Second line]
```

This is the test I am running:

```
test("Paths should have a .append method") {
    val pth = Paths.get("test.txt")
    val data = " line_1\nSecond"
    try {
    pth.append(pth,"line_1\n")
    pth.append(pth,"Second line\n")
     assert(new String(Files.readAllBytes(pth)) == "line_1\nSecond line\n")
    }
    finally {
      Files.deleteIfExists(pth)
     }
 }
```

Comment: Your `append` method takes two parameters and you're only handing it one.

Comment: I changed the method. However, now I get a different error

Comment: What's the different error?

Comment: I have updated that as well.

Comment: Your `append` method is writing an extra `\n` on each call.

Comment: Ok. But the problem seems that it is not writing "first line' into the file

Comment: Sorry, I meant ' line_1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File writer needs to be in append mode. `new FileWriter(file, true);`

Also the `append` method will put an extra `\n` in there the way it's currently written.